# How to fix Error: Duplicate resources when generate android build

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

Here i am trying to generate build for android device and i get an error which is defined below, my project is in ionic with fire-store(beta version).
Can any one help me to fix it:

```
    BUILD FAILED in 2s
    [string/google_api_key] ...............\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml    [string/google_api_key] ...............\platforms\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
    :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
    22 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 20 up-to-date
    (node:6472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > [string/google_app_id] ................\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml   [string/google_app_id] ................\platforms\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
      [string/google_api_key] ................\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml  [string/google_api_key] ................\platforms\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 2s
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (..............\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
    (node:6472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:6472) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Found same error. Did you get any solution?

Comment: @AnkitMaheshwari yes , i get the solution.
Here you need to delete google_app_id & google_api_key from android.json file.

Comment: Thanks @VaishaliVC I tried that but I usually generate production build using Ionic Pro Package build. There we can't control android.json file.

Comment: @AnkitMaheshwari First try to solve an error in simple build. Once it removed then generate production build.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with cordova-plugin-facebook4.

The documentation had suggested I add:

```
<config-file parent="/resources" target="./res/values/strings.xml">
    <string name="fb_app_id">XXX</string>
    <string name="fb_app_name">XXX</string>
</config-file>
```

along with the specific plugin config:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^3.1.0">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="XXX" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="XXX" />
</plugin>
```

Since something updated, the `config-file` version causes this issue.

Remove the related items from `config-file`.